# Apply function to each group where the group are splitted in multiple files without concatenating all the files

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

My data come from BigQuery exported to GCS bucket as CSV file and if the file size is quite massive, BigQuery will automatically split the data into several chunk. With time series in mind, the time series might be scattered across different files. I have a custom function that I want to applied to each `TimeseriesID`.

Here's some constraint of the data:

- The data is sorted by `TimeseriesID` and `TimeID`
- The number of row of each files is may vary, but at minimum 1 row (which is very unlikely)
- The starting of `TimeID` is not always 0
- The length of each time series may vary but at maximum it will only scattered across 2 files. No time series scatter in 3 different files.

Here's the initial setup to illustrate the problem:

```
# Please take note this is just for simplicity. The actual goal is not to calculate mean for all group, but to apply a custom_func to each Timeseries ID
def custom_func(x):
    return np.mean(x) 

# Please take note this is just for simplicity. In actual, I read the file one by one since reading all the data is not possible
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['A','A','A','B'],"TimeID":[0,1,2,4],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['B','B','B','C'],"TimeID":[5,6,7,8],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['C','D','D','D'],"TimeID":[9,1,2,3],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
```

This should be pretty trivial if I can just `concat` all the files but the problem is if I `concat` all the dataframe then it won't fit in the memory.

The output I desired is should be similar to this but without `concat` all the files.

```py
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=0).groupby('TimeseriesID').agg({"value":simple_func})
```

I'm also aware about `vaex` and `dask` but I want to stick with simple pandas for time being.
I'm also open to solution which involve modifying the BigQuery to split the files better.

Comment: You menton that you are using simple pandas. You are using normal `Panda` or [Panda GBQ](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-gbq/)? It won't fit to the memory, are you getting any error?

Comment: About 'TimeID' relevance, as mention in the question its only a value which is use for sorting and it may not always be 0 but besides that there are no key information which may indicate that is used for the desired output calculation. The only columns in play are 'TimeseriesID' and 'value'

Comment: @PjoterS I'm not reading directly from BigQuery. I export the bigquery table to csv file in GCS bucket, after that I'm using pd.read_csv to read from the GCS bucket. I will edit my question.

Comment: also regarding TimeID, since the data already sorted by TimeID, yes it might be not useful to use TimeID. I'm just putting it so people understand the nature of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach presented by op to use concat with million of records would be overkill for memories/other resources.

I have tested OP code using Google Colab Nootebooks and this was a bad approach

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

# Please take note this is just for simplicity. The actual goal is not to calculate mean for all group, but to apply a custom_func to each Timeseries ID

def  custom_func(x):
    return np.mean(x)

# Please take note this is just for simplicity. In actual, I read the file one by one since reading all the data is not possible
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['A','A','A','B'],"TimeID":[0,1,2,4],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['B','B','B','C'],"TimeID":[5,6,7,8],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['C','D','D','D'],"TimeID":[9,1,2,3],"value":[10,20,5,30]})

start = time.time()
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby('TimeseriesID').agg({"value":custom_func})
elapsed = (time.time() - start)

print(elapsed)
print(df.head())
```

output will be:

```
0.023952960968017578 
                value 
TimeseriesID A 11.666667 
             B 16.250000 
             C 20.000000 
             D 18.333333
```

As you can see, 'concat' takes time to process. Due to few records this is not perceived.
The approach should be as follow:

1. Get files with data that you are going to process. ie: only workable columns.
2. Create a dictionary from the processed files key and values. if necessary, obtain values per key in a necessary file. You can store the results in a 'results' directory as json/csv:

> A.csv will have all key 'A' values
> ...
> n.csv will have all key 'n' values

3. Iterate trough results directory and start building your final output inside a dictionary.

> {'A': [10, 20, 5], 'B': [30, 10, 20, 5], 'C': [30, 10], 'D': [20, 5, 30]}

4. apply custom function to each key value list.

> {'A': 11.666666666666666, 'B': 16.25, 'C': 20.0, 'D': 18.333333333333332}

You can check the logic using below code, I use json to store the data:

```
from google.colab import files
import json
import pandas as pd

#initial dataset
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['A','A','A','B'],"TimeID":[0,1,2,4],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['B','B','B','C'],"TimeID":[5,6,7,8],"value":[10,20,5,30]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"TimeseriesID":['C','D','D','D'],"TimeID":[9,1,2,3],"value":[10,20,5,30]})

#get unique keys and its values
df1.groupby('TimeseriesID')['value'].apply(list).to_json('df1.json')
df2.groupby('TimeseriesID')['value'].apply(list).to_json('df2.json')
df3.groupby('TimeseriesID')['value'].apply(list).to_json('df3.json')

#as this is an example you can download the output as jsons
files.download('df1.json')
files.download('df2.json')
files.download('df3.json')
```

**Update 06/10/2021**
I have tuned code for OPs needs. This part creates refined files.

```
from google.colab import files
import json

#you should use your own function to get the data from the file
def retrieve_data(uploaded,file):
  return json.loads(uploaded[file].decode('utf-8'))

#you should use your own function to get a list of files to process
def retrieve_files():
  return files.upload()

key_list =[]
#call a function that gets a list of files to process
file_to_process = retrieve_files()

#read every raw file:
for file in file_to_process: 
  file_data = retrieve_data(file_to_process,file)

  for key,value in file_data.items(): 
    if key not in key_list: 
      key_list.append(key)
      with open(f'{key}.json','w') as new_key_file:
        new_json = json.dumps({key:value})
        new_key_file.write(new_json)

    else:
      with open(f'{key}.json','r+') as key_file:
        raw_json = key_file.read()
        old_json = json.loads(raw_json)
        new_json = json.dumps({key:old_json[key]+value})

        key_file.seek(0)
        key_file.write(new_json)

for key in key_list:
  files.download(f'{key}.json')

print(key_list)
```

**Update 07/10/2021**
I have updated code to avoid confusion. This part process refined files.

```
import time
import numpy as np

#Once we get the refined values we can use it to apply custom functions
def custom_func(x):
    return np.mean(x) 

#Get key and data content from single json
def get_data(file_data):
    content = file_data.popitem()
    return content[0],content[1]

#load key list and build our refined dictionary
refined_values = []

#call a function that gets a list of files to process
file_to_process = retrieve_files()

start = time.time()
#read every refined file:
for file in file_to_process: 
  #read content of file n
  file_data = retrieve_data(file_to_process,file)
  
  #parse and apply function per file read
  key,data = get_data(file_data)
  func_output = custom_func(data)

  #start building refined list
  refined_values.append([key,func_output])

elapsed = (time.time() - start)
print(elapsed)
  
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(refined_values,columns=['TimerSeriesID','value']).sort_values(by=['TimerSeriesID'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df.head())
```

output will be:

```
0.00045609474182128906
  TimerSeriesID      value
0             A  11.666667
1             B  16.250000
2             C  20.000000
3             D  18.333333
```

summarize:

- When handling large datasets, you should always need to focus on the data that you are going to use and keep it minimal. Only using the workable values.
- Processing times are faster when operations are performed by basic operators or python native libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, love the clarity of your answer. So basically for the first part I will do a loop for each of my file to convert it into json.file.  
For second part, since I have the access to GCS bucket, than instead of uploading each file one by one, I can list all my file (using something like glob) and append them to json. But this approach will break the order of the value, I think we need to modify it to append the pair of time index and value so it can be sorted later.  
And since your solution use looping for each file and each json item, I think we need multiprocessing here.

Comment: Hello Vinson Ciawandy, please check the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just realize that in the `#read every refined file` to create `refined_values ` variable, doesn't it essentially the same with just reading all the data but just in json format? Wouldn't it blow the memory ?

Comment: I think the process of applying  `custom_func` can be done on this loop `for file in file_to_process:`. It should work right? So no need to gather all the data and just apply the func for each `file_data` since  for each `file_data` already contains a complete series?

Comment: Hello Vinson Ciawandy, I have updated the code to answer your questions. In short, yes, the correct approach should be to handle each file individually to avoid memory consumption. Even if processing that way the consumption remains high, you should be  limiting your chunks into manageable sizes. Also, you can use multiprocessing to speed this filtering process.